# PHP Session Variables Session_name

Tags: php, session-variables

Good day!

How can I change the name of my session_name() variable. Below are my sample codes from php.net

```
<?php
$previous_name = session_name("WebsiteID");
echo "The previous session name was $previous_name<br />";
?>
```

It still echoes PHPSESSID instead of WebsiteID, I'm using PHP 7 and alsor trying it to my other workstation running PHP 5.3. Did I missed something?? Please Advise.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to also "start" the session AFTER you set the session name with session_name($newName). Use session_start() after session_name() and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

> Return Values
>
> Returns the name of the current session. If name is given and function
>   updates the session name, name of the old session is returned

so this is expected behaviour: the result is the OLD value, not the new value.

That's why the example text is talking about `The previous session`, and not `the current session` I'd assume :D

Comment: Thanks Nanne for your swift response, By the way, How can I get the current session name if that's the case?

Comment: Just check the manual please: `session_name() returns the name of the current session. If name is given, session_name() will update the session name and return the old session name.`. So if you call `session_name()`, you'll get the current session.

Comment: (basically, this means if you call `session_name` you'll get the "current" name, and if you provide a new name, it will update it after returning the current one. So it's a bit ... php-ish in its behaviour, but that's kinda how it works. )

Comment: no problem, please check  the 'accepted answer' mark if you feel that's appropriate and/or use the up (or down) vote button :D